# Text editor capable to join groups of N lines

Tags: text-editor

I will give an example where N = 3

The input looks like this:

```
A
B
C

D
E
F

G
H
I
```

The output must look like this:

```
A     D     G

B     E     H

C     F     I
```

(the input might have 12 lines instead of 9 though. Or 30, or 300..)

But most of the time I need to join, in the selected text, the top half with the bottom half. In other words, I select N lines and I need to join the first N/2 lines with the last N/2 lines. I will give an example:

The input looks like this:

```
A
B
C
D

1
2
3
4
```

The output must look like this:

```
A     1
B     2
C     3
D     4
```

(In this case the value of N was 8)

Is it possible to do something like that using regex or macros?

Note, there is a similar question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/678046/how-to-merge-lines-every-3-rows-in-notepad), but that's completely distinct to this one though

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do in a text editor. Text editor which has "vertical blocks" selection.

- select vert-block for one column
- Cut to clipboard
- move caret to desired pos in first line
- Paste from clipboard

(For ex, I use CudaText. It has vertical blocks; allows cursor after line-end, so no problem to paste at desired pos).

Comment: Indeed, thanks. Although it would be nice to have an interface to simply ask you for the value of N and then to do the rest of the work, for the currently selected text. But, most likely, I would have to write a plugin in order to get that.

Answer (score 1):

On unix, you can use the command line tools `head`, `tail` and `paste`.

```
       paste - merge lines of files

       Write lines consisting of the sequentially corresponding lines 
       from each FILE, separated by TABs, to standard output.
```

The solution sketched below might require some finetuning from your side.

Assuming your input

```
A
B
C
D

1
2
3
4
```

is stored in `file1.txt`,

do this:

`head -5 file1.txt  > f1.txt ; tail -n +6 file1.txt  > f2.txt`

to write them out in two files.

Then do

`paste f1.txt f2.txt`

Result:

```
A   1
B   2
C   3
D   4
```

You can do all on one line with

```
n=9; head -$((n/2)) file1.txt  > f1.txt ; tail -n +$((n/2 + 2)) file1.txt  > f2.txt; paste f1.txt f2.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm using GNUWin32 for using unix tools on Windows. It would be more interesting if the script would just ask you the value of N and then do the rest of the job though.

Comment: the one-liner has a single parameter `n=9` which you can change according to your wishes, e.g. to `n=256` to write fetch+split the first 256 lines from your infile.